# How do I use userChrome.css to remove the magnifying glass from modern versions of Firefox/Iceweasel?

Tags: firefox

A quick google search will find a lot of sites saying to add this to `userChrome.css`:

```
#go-button-stack, .search-go-button-stack {
  display: none !important;
}
```

to remove the magnifying glass from the search bar, but on Iceweasel 17 and Firefox 25 on Linux, that doesn't have an effect. All of the sites I can find mention it as a solution for Firefox 2 and 3, but is there a way to remove this icon in recent versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for Firefox 25:

```
.search-go-button {
display: none !important;
}
```